# Loop help: string vector to 3D char vector

Tags: c++, loops, vector, multidimensional-array

I'm new to C++ and this is my first attempt at a 3D vector. I'm trying to take an input file of variable length like this:

```
xxooo##xx
xoxxxoxoo
xxx#oxoo#
oxxxoxoox
xxoooo#xx
xxxo#o###
xxo#o#xxo
x##oxxoox
xxx##oxoo
xoxx#xooo
```

And turn it into a 3D char vector where each line is a 3x3 box with the first three characters being the first row, the next three the 2nd row, and the last three the 3rd row. For example the first row of the input should turn into this:

```
x x o
o o #
# x x
```

This is my attempt at a solution, but I feel that I've probably made several mistakes:

```
vector<vector<vector<char> > > makeBoard(vector<string> iflines)
{// Function to fill game boards from input strings

vector<vector<vector<char> > > charboard;

for (int i = 0; i != iflines.size(); i++) 
{   
    for (int j = 0; j < 9; j=j+3)
    {
        charboard[i][j/3][0] = iflines[i][j]; 
        charboard[i][j/3][1] = iflines[i][j+1];
        charboard[i][j/3][2] = iflines[i][j+2];     
    }   
}
    return charboard;
}
```

Would someone please help me out here?

edit: edited from suggestions plus a couple things I tried to fix. I get the error: `Segmentation fault: 11`. When I try to run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling push_back on a `char`. You need to do

```
charboard[i][j/3][k] = iflines[i][j]
```

Since you are working with a fixed 3x3 array you don't need to use a `std::vector` for inner components. A `std:array` would suffice, something like

```
using GameBoard = std::array<std::array<char, 3>, 3>;
vector<GameBoard> charboard;
```

In addition you don't need to use if/else to compute `k`, there is the modulo `%` operator which yields the remainder of the division so it's perfectly fine for your situation:

```
charboard[i][j/3][j%3] = iflines[i][j]
```

Comment: I used a vector because the size of the input file is variable so while the boxes are all 3x3 I don't know how many I'll need it to make

Comment: i edited with the changes of pushback to `=` and changed the `k` to `j%3`and I get segmentation fault, so I think there's a problem with how I set this up, but I'm having trouble thinking it through